# How would I make it so that a string works inside of quotes?

Tags: python, string

How would I make it so that, in the example of:

```
color = "White"
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//img[@alt = "color"]').click()
```

that instead of "color" in the "driver.find" line, it would be replaced with "White" as I defined it above? Everything that I've tried just turns "color" into a variable by itself and doesn't replace it with "White" like I intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you are not forrmating the string,

```py
color = "White"
driver.find_element_by_xpath(f'//img[@alt = "{color}"]').click()
```

Use the above code for python3.x and up
For Python versions 2.x, use:

```py
color = "White"
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//img[@alt = "{}"]'.format(color)).click()
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes with format strings:

```
color = "White"
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//img[@alt = \"{}\"]'.format(color)).click()
```

Also in python 3.7 + use f-strings:

```
color = "White"
driver.find_element_by_xpath(f'//img[@alt = \"{color}\"]').click()
```

Comment: [f-strings were introduced in python 3.6](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)